# How to build a blender build in Xcode 5?

Tags: python, build, xcode5, blender

I have been trying to create my own custom build of blender following through with the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac) but I have had no luck with actually building the final version with X Code. I have about 140 warning messages and 32 error messages. I just can't figure it out. Below is a section of the code with the errors in it. I would greatly appreciate any help I could get on this one!

```
  "_Controller_actuators_length", referenced from:


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::Controller::Controller_actuators_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_CurveMapping_curves_length", referenced from:


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::CurveMapping::CurveMapping_curves_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshColorLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshColorLayer::MeshColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshLoopColorLayer::MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshPaintMaskLayer::MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer::MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshSkinVertexLayer::MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshTextureFaceLayer::MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshTexturePolyLayer::MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshUVLoopLayer::MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer::MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer::MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length", referenced from:


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer::MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_Sensor_controllers_length", referenced from:


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::Sensor::Sensor_controllers_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  "_Spline_points_length", referenced from:


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_python.o)


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_session.o)


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_camera.o)


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_sync.o)


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_object.o)


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_shader.o)


  BL::Spline::Spline_points_length_wrap(PointerRNA*) in libbf_intern_cycles.a(blender_curves.o)


  ...


  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64


  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could you add the details of the errors? Perhaps focus on one or two. The link you provided could die so it'd be of little help to future visitors who might be encountering the same issue. Plus it'd make it more easier to find.

Comment: Added the 'error' section of the code above.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working, just had to change the type from debug to release.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and solved by your last comment.

Comment: That is not really a solution, you are only changing the type of release... what you lost doing this is you can't put a breakpoint and stop at the hit of it in execution, even that you put it there.

Comment: And it is also probable that you like I have copied inside the libraries downloaded from SVN the `release libs`... because in the SVN there is no `debug library` provided for third party libs (at less where Xcode first try to search them like `.../blender-build/lib/darwin-9.x.universal/thirdPartyLib1/lib/Debug`) After we copy like that, we get this error (I will try again for know if this is really the step "2" after solving the linker errors of libraries not found in `.../blender-build/lib/darwin-9.x.universal/thirdPartyLib1/lib/Debug`.

Comment: Update: aparently this is caused by a bug in CMake's XCode generator: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15794

Comment: After asking the CMake developer, fired another issue for this problem : https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15806

Answer (score 5):

A little late but I found a workaround for this since I was in the same boat. Maybe it’ll help someone else searching for a solution. The clue came from the cmakefile for bf_intern_cycles:

```
# avoid link failure with clang 3.4 debug
if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang" AND NOT ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS '3.4')
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -gline-tables-only")
endif()
```

**Solution:** All you have to do it set “*-gline-tables-only*” on the bf_intern_cycles target under "Other C++ Flags” and it should compile properly and breakpoints seem to work fine.

Tod

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to debug the app and go step by step (not only been able to compile/run it as when you switch to release in the scheme) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32025581/682603 basically you need to disable cycles in CMake configuration.

Yeah, you will not have cycles for this build, but at less you will have the possibility to watch step by step all the other things (that is at less to this day I guess).