# Building Blender for breakpoints/Debug in Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, debugging, xcode6, blender

**TL;RD** Following http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac for Xcode what are the steps that let you add breakpoints/watches and correctly debug the executable on OS X?

My spec

`Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)
OSX 10.10.4 (14E46)
CMake 3.3.0 GUI build with QT 4.8.6`

## The long description

I did follow the instructions so I set the scheme as suggested as for Xcode 5 (did let debug as default) but

1. First time cmake fails because there is no `numpy` there is no `numpy` (release or debug) inside https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/darwin-9.x.universal/python/lib/python3.4/ also from the console output munpy is searched on something like `/Users/tyoc213/blender-build/blender/../lib/darwin-9.x.universal/python/lib/python3.4/python3.4/site-packages/numpy` also you can see that it search on `python3.4/python3.4` which is weird.
2. On the second run it says that it will skip `numpy` on install(ation). you can see the cmake output here https://gist.github.com/tyoc213/aea0fb541383dc06981a
3. So we now can generate Xcode project, we open the generated blender project with Xcode configure the scheme as on the dev-wiki and wait it fails at blinker step.

## The only plausible fix for debug scheme is no fix at all, use release scheme

There is only one "fix" for compile&run for this and it is *to change the scheme* to *Release*, but even having checked `Debug application` and that Xcode attach on start to the process, breakpoints don't work.

## The debug scheme

So the problem in Debug scheme is this: [How to build a blender build in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178003/how-to-build-a-blender-build-in-xcode-5) basically there are references from libbf_intern_cycles.a that are not found: `_Controller_actuators_length`, `_CurveMapping_curves_length`, `_MeshColorLayer_data_length`, `_MeshLoopColorLayer_data_length`, `_MeshPaintMaskLayer_data_length`, `_MeshPolygonFloatPropertyLayer_data_length`, `_MeshPolygonIntPropertyLayer_data_length`, `_MeshPolygonStringPropertyLayer_data_length`, `_MeshSkinVertexLayer_data_length`, `_MeshTextureFaceLayer_data_length`, `_MeshTexturePolyLayer_data_length`, `_MeshUVLoopLayer_data_length`, `_MeshVertexFloatPropertyLayer_data_length`, `_MeshVertexIntPropertyLayer_data_length`, `_MeshVertexStringPropertyLayer_data_length`, `_Sensor_controllers_length`, `_Spline_points_length` this are `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Any suggestions in the correct setup for **debug** and put **break points** then do **steps, threads** with Xcode and **watch variables** and so on?.

Comment: I don't know XCode, but Blender is not different to other CMake projects. just set the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug`, rebuild. And you should see debug symbols.

Comment: Note that `numpy` issue is a warning, not an error.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178003/how-to-build-a-blender-build-in-xcode-5

Both are a linking error for debug builds.

Comment: Thought it is a duplicate, people could think it is solved because the OP say "for get it I got it working"... while he doesn't see the usefuless to have a correct debug scheme where you can put visual breakpoints, add watched, see stack and locals on hit of the breakpoint and so on. That is why asked again with a more specific tittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for the moment that I have found to be able to put breakpoints in Xcode and do step by step, see locals and so on, is to disable cycles in CMake.

Maybe I should post this as an error in the build process at less for CMake, I don't know if I can build scons inside Xcode and debug it inside Xcode.

Comment: I try to install the CUDA package (ver 7) and compile Blender with WITH_CYCLES_CUDA_BINARY, and still encounter the same error, is there a way to compile with cycles ?

Comment: Change to release scheme inside Xcode, it should run but you can't debug that way Blender inside Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to build cycles with Debug configuration, how can I tell the linker to find symbols in the list on the original question?

Comment: In Cmake you can configure to build with debug (I think it also work with scons)... but as far as I can tell, the build *on OS X* for *cycles+debug* is breaked as today at less for CMake, so you will get the errors listed above). You need to disable build with cycles in order to debug step by step on debug mode in OS X.

Comment: Hi ! thanks for your reply, I post the same question to bf-committers mailing list, too. It is a work-around for the time being.

Comment: Have never post there, if you have any reply that really solves the problem would be nice to listen here please (being the problem for me: being able to debug inside Xcode do step by step, watch locals and so on). NOTE that it all work if you use the release configuration in Xcode

Comment: Hi, by this mailing list, it is working now. http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2015-October/046008.html